# Online courses/resources for panel data analysis in python?

Tags: regression, python, references, panel-data, stepwise-regression

I am keen to learn more about panel data models using python, but I do not find related courses or many resources online. In particular, I usually find general statistics courses with Python or, courses that are specific for panel data regression but in R. Any chance anyone has suggestions/places where I could look at?
In case someone is familiar with the topic, I want to build a linear, model using stepwise regression, predicting a binary outcome, so any resource specific to the topic is highly appreciated.

Comment: For a binary outcome, look into logistic regression. Search this site!

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately Logistic regression does not work for my dataset

Comment: Maybe you could augment the post, explaining why logistic regression cannot be used?

Comment: Thanks for the help but here I do not need to discuss my model, I am looking for online courses on econometrics/advanced statistics with pyhton!